# How to show Oauth Consent screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-oauth

I am trying to user gmail api. Google is asking me to make a video with  demo of Oauth consent screen. 
While searching in the internet I have found solutions for web and native android android. The docs of flutter packages googleapi and googleapi_auth were not very helful. If anyone has already implemented any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably too late but here is the code for

```
'    clientViaUserConsent(_clientid, _scopes, userPrompt)
    .then((AuthClient client) {
  //your code to authenticate any of your google platform
```

}

Here is the userPrompt function

```
void userPrompt(String url) async {
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
  print("Launching url");
  launch(url);
} else {
  print("unable to launch the url");
}}
```

So whenever the clientviauserprompt is called the prompt function will launch the url to the default browser for the user consent.
You have to use urllauncher dependency for this.